# Service not started while booting

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

`enter code here`Trying to start the service but it is not started on Booting while service is running perfectly during the start of the app for first time.

This is the Receiver  and i want use switch case because there is lot many things i have to start using receiver.

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent;
 switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case SmackService.NEW_MESSAGE:
                Log.i("TAG", "processMessage() BroadCast Recieve");
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                Log.i("TAG", "Boot");
                Toast.makeText(context, "case", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SmackService.class);
                    context.startService(serviceIntent);
                break;
}
}
```

Manifest Content :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name="com.example.abhishek.im.ChatReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.tlt.rx.msg" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Service Class

```
public class SmackService extends Service {
  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        user_data = new HashMap<>();
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(BUNDLE_MSG_SYNC)) {
            doChatSync = intent.getBooleanExtra(BUNDLE_MSG_SYNC, false);
        }
        if (intent != null) {
            String email, password, name;
            email = intent.getExtras().getString("email");
            password = intent.getExtras().getString("password");
            name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
            activity=intent.getExtras().getString("activity");
            user_data.put("email", email);
            user_data.put("password", password);
            user_data.put("name", name);
            start(user_data);
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Starting the service manually:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signing in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmackService.class);
                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                    intent.putExtra("password", password);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("activity", "MainActivity");
                    startService(intent);
```

nt);

Comment: Permissions go outside of the `<application>` tags, if you don't have it there.

Comment: <uses-permission> is outside of <application> tags so if any other problem please let me know @MikeM.

Comment: Do you have any activities in your application? Have you started the app manually before booting your device?

Comment: Also , post the code you use to start the `Service` manually,

Comment: yes my app is having activities and i am starting the service manually for the first time.
Code is edited : @DavidWasser

Comment: Are you booting, or **re**booting?

Comment: the activity which starts the service is kind of a login so after first time when i boot i don't want to login again so i directly continued to the next activity so i want when i start next activity the connection should be created again for that i start the service again so i am booting again to start the service @TimCastelijns

Comment: Booting what exactly, your device?

Comment: when i start my app again @TimCastelijns

Comment: That is not what we call booting, and that is not what the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is for

Comment: than how can i start the service when my app starts again @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty clear what is happening. On boot, your `BroadcastReceiver` is getting called. It then starts the `Service` like this:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SmackService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

in `onStartCommand()`, you do this:

```
email = intent.getExtras().getString("email");
```

Since there are no "extras" in the `Intent`, `getExtras()` returns `null` and you call `getString()` on a `null` reference, which then throws a `NullPointerException`, causing your `Service` to crash.

End of story.